# MySQL database backup every day using java code

Tags: mysql, java

We are developing a Java web application using Spring, Hibernate and MySQL.

I want our application to automatically backup the MySQL database daily; is there any way to accomplish that with Java code?

Comment: u may use one facility of mysql that can be rollback the data of your database

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do.

1. Write a script to create the backup using the "mysqldump" tool available at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html - Google "mysql backup unix/windows script" to find some examples.
2. Use a task scheduler to run this script. On UNIX this could be "cron", Windows as a "task scheduler". Best to do so at times when the app is under low-usage.

It is worth while putting some backup file cycling into the script so that you keep, say, every backup from the last week and delete the rest.

Also remember to backup to a physically different disk from the database itself so you have a backup if the disk dies.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Quartz-scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to schedule the backup, take a look [here](http://www.java-only.com/LoadTutorial.javaonly?id=32) on how to schedule an automatic Hibernate backup.